# How to always scroll into view for particular div element in React js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is below sample code in which I am facing scroll to top issue whenever user is interacting.
I have added the dummy space with the help of padding on top and bottom, so that whenever user interact, it should always scroll into view. So how can I achieve scroll into view with below code ?

Here content is dynamic, sometime it can be little bit more or less, I am always wanted into view part.

Currently what happening in the application, when we click on next button (assume we have quiz QA)  , it automatically  scroll to the top and we don't have such kind of function in application which move toward the top upon navigating question in the quiz. So, I always wanted into the view part.
That's the reason I added dummy space to replicate the issue which I am facing

```
return (
<div>
<div style={{padding: 400px, background: #eee}}> Dummy Space
</div>
<div id="show-content">
{/* inside this div I mounting my react app component assume, I have some quiz question along with some button prev and next */}
</div>
<div style={{padding: 400px, background: #eee}}> Dummy Space
</div>
</div>
)
}
```

You might be saying to remove dummy space related stuff, but there are some other app exist in those area in which I don't have control over there

Comment: You can do this by using the `overflow` property of CSS. You can set this to `scroll`, this makes sure that the element you put it on always show the scroll. If you make the height/width fixed it will now always be that size and scrollable through the total size. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.php

Answer (score 4):

Create a `ref` for the `#show-content` div and scroll to the `div` using `scrollIntoView`.

```
const divRef = useRef();

const scrollToElement = () => {
  const {current} = divRef
   if (current !== null){
     current.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"})
   }
}
```

If you navigate from another route, use the following code in the same componenet as the `#show-content` div:

```
   useEffect(scrollToElement, [])
```

If you are on the same route, call `scrollToElement` in `onClick`.

Use the `ref` object like this:

```
<div id="show-content" ref={divRef}>
{/* inside this div I mounting my react app component assume, I have some quiz question along with some button prev and next */}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.scrollTo(x,y)` if know the height of the component/view. you can use this in built browser function when your component mounts:

```
useEffect(()=>{
window.scrollTo(0,200)
},[])
```